# How can i split an AVL tree at a given node at time O(log(n))?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I've been busting my head trying all kinds of ways but the best I got is O(log^2(n)).
the exact question is:
make a function `Split(AVLtree T, int k)` which returns 2 AVL trees (like a tuple) such that all values in T1 are lower than or equal to k and the rest are in T2. k is not necessarily in the tree. time must be  O(log(n)).
Assume efficient implementation of AVL tree and I managed to make a merge function with time O(log(|h1-h2|)).

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, given that you have the merge function!

Do a regular successor search in the tree for k. This will trace out a path through the tree from the root to that successor node. Imagine cutting every edge traced out on the path this way, which will give you a collection of "pennants," single nodes with legal AVL trees hanging off to the sides. Then, show that if you merge them back together in the right order, the costs of the merges form a telescoping sum that adds up to O(log n).

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this methode before but I must have fumbled the math since I got O(log^2(n)). Will try again.